# How to use Anaconda without adding to PATH and without admin access in windows 10?

Tags: python, anaconda

I do not have admin access to my work laptop also I am not able to add environment variables as it asks for admin credentials. I am trying to create a .bat file to be able to run python program, usually it looks like this:

```
python filename.py
pause
```

I tried adding the full path of the `python.exe` file like this

```
U:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe filename.py
```

Using that it shows

> ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

and various Import errors.
I can run the files from anaconda prompt without errors.
I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need admin access to add environment variables. you can put environment varaible for the whole system (admin required) or your single user account.

Comment: When I type in "Environment variables" in search and click on it, A popup appears asking me for username and password.  
https://i.imgur.com/K1aNLF9.png

Comment: you have 2 options, for logged user and for all users, click to edit variables for your user, shouldn’t ask you for u/p, but if it does, it’s your u/p with whom you logged in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to change environment variable for your account. Search for "Edit environment variables for your account" and add Python and Anacodna locations to PATH. You can check location by `where conda` and `where python` commands in Anaconda Prompt.

Comment: This is it. There are two different options in the search which I did not notice. "Edit the system's environment variables" and "Edit environment variables for your account." . Thanks for the heads up.